# How to auto sync Amazon seller orders with SP-API?

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

Developing an app that should allow customers to connect their Amazon seller account, which would export all of their unshipped orders. Once tracking numbers are provided for their unshipped orders on my dashboard, it would send the tracking numbers back to their Amazon seller account and mark that specific order(s) as shipped.

I have been stuck on the concept of doing this. I have it setup to where the customer has to manually enter keys, but that would be too difficult for customers. I want a simpler setup that will request the user to signin to their Amazon account like the below example:

[image]

[image]

I've been through the docs but I am not quite seeing how other businesses are achieving this. Could someone please outline the flow to have a similar setup?

Comment: Have you tried https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/website-authorization-workflow ?